# Powerstrip's red indicator is flickering like crazy as long as no light is turned on in the room

Tags: voltage, current

I have a Belkin power strip with a red light indicator in it. I have used it for years and it functioned properly. Last night I noticed its red light flickering like crazy, i.e. constantly turning off for a fraction of a second and coming right back. Whenever I turn on any lamp in the room, the red light indicator lights up without fading or going away, just as it is supposed to, but as soon as I turn off all light in the room, the power strip's indicator starts flickering again. This happens when the power strip has nothing connected to it. Not sure if I should be concerned.

Does that mean I have "unstable current" in the socket or something like that and when I turn on the light the current starts flowing in room's wires and "stabilizes"?

Answer (score 5):

Nope. It means that the neon bulb in your power strip is approaching the end of its useful life.

From what I understand, incident light that impinges the bulb reduces the amount of energy that the neon gas inside the bulb requires to break down and conduct.

Comment: . . .and iirc cosmic rays have a similar effect, hence at least some of the random flashes in the dark.

Comment: Cool stuff I did not know. +1 Dwayne and peterG.